# binding data from same object to same multiple directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Hello I am little confused about how can I bind the same directive with different data from the same object

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('appController', appController)
        .directive('userForm', userForm);
    /**@Injectable*/
    function appController($http) {
        let vm = this;
        vm.user = {
            userName: 'Test User',
            email: 'test@gmail.com',
            number: '1456',
            address: 'zyz',
            state: 'abcd',
            city: 'xyz'
        };
    }
    function userForm() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data:'='
            },
            templateUrl: 'public/app/form.directive.html',
            controller: 'appController',
            link: function (scope, attr, element) {

            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<legend>{{headerLabel}}</legend>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label1.label1}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.userName" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label2}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label3}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="number">
    </div>
</div>

<!--Main Index -->
<user-form data="vm.user"></user-form>
<user-form data="vm.user"></user-form>
```

Here I have used same directive two times and I want to bind the first directive with personal info like username, email and second directive should bind with address info.Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you would want to do that, using a directive for two different purposes. I suggest creating 2 different directives for it. If you still want it, you can have a logic inside link in the directive function to perform different logics. Its not very elegant, but what you asked for is not either(imho)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('appController', appController)
        .directive('userForm', userForm);
    /**@Injectable*/
    function appController($http) {
        let vm = this;
        vm.user = {
            userName: 'Test User',
            email: 'test@gmail.com',
            number: '1456',
            address: 'zyz',
            state: 'abcd',
            city: 'xyz'
        };
    }
    function userForm() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data:'=', 
                type:'@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'public/app/form.directive.html',
            controller: 'appController',
            link: function (scope, attr, element) {
                switch(scope.type){
                   case 'name_info':
                    //logic for name based info
                    break;
                   case 'address_info':
                    //logic for address based info
                    break;
                   default:



                }

            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<legend>{{headerLabel}}</legend>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label1.label1}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.userName" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label2}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">{{label3}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="number">
    </div>
</div>

<user-form data="vm.user" type="name_info"></user-form>
<user-form data="vm.user" type="address_info"></user-form>
```

Comment: I want to do this because actually its just demo  , I have a object in which it contains answer description , answer image , question description and question text with preview and editor so I don't want to create two directory for that ,instead I can use one directive to display then and binding with model for edit.